# Sum over bilinear form in finite-field vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear map over the finite-field vector space $(F_2)^n$, i.e., an $F_2$-valued  $n\times n$ matrix, not necessarily symmetric. I'm interested in the sum
$$\sum_{X\in F_2^n} X^T A X\;.$$
Is there a way to efficiently compute this sum? Can one say anything interesting about when this sum is going to be $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interesting cases ($n\geq 3$) this is always $0$. Observe that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in F_2^n} x^T A x &= \sum_{x\in F_2^n}\mathrm{Tr}( x^T A x)\\
&= \sum_{x\in F_2^n}\mathrm{Tr}( A x x^T)\\
&= \mathrm{Tr}( A \sum_{x\in F_2^n} x x^T)
\end{align*}

Let $B\triangleq\sum_{x\in F_2^n} x x^T$, then $B_{ii}=\sum_{x\in F_2^n} e_i^T x x^T e_i = 2^{n-1} \sum_{a\in F_2} aa=2^{n-1}$ which is $0$ as $n\geq 2$ and $1$ for $n=1$. Now if you take a non diagonal element $B_{ij}=\sum_{x\in F_2^n} e_i^Tx x e_j^T=2^{n-2}\sum_{a\in F_2} a\sum_{b\in F_2} b=2^{n-2}$, this is $1$ for $n=2$ and $0$ for $n\geq 3$ (the case $n=1$ does exist because there would not be diagonal elements).

In conclusion, if $n\geq 3$, $B=0$ and so $\sum_{x\in F_2^n} x^T A x =0$. If $n= 2$, then you get $\sum_{x\in F_2^n} x^T A x = A_{12}+A_{21}$ and for $n=1$ you get $\sum_{x\in F_2^n} x^T A x = A_{11}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Embarrassingly, I realize I asked the wrong question. I forgot to exponentiate the "action". Sorry about that! I made a new post, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4454008/487705. If you have any insights about the "correct" question as well, I'd appreciate very much!

Comment: I'm going to take a look, can't promise anything of course.