# Sum over exponentiated bilinear form in finite-field vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $A$ be a linear map over the finite-field vector space $(F_2)^n$, i.e., an $F_2$-valued  $n\times n$ matrix, not necessarily symmetric. I'm interested in the sum
$$\sum_{X\in F_2^n} (-1)^{X^T A X}\;,$$
with (obviously) $(-1)^0=1\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(-1)^1=-1\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a way to efficiently compute this sum? Can one say anything interesting about when this sum is going to be $0$?

Comment: This question now has an answer on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424746/sum-over-exponentiated-bilinear-form-in-finite-field-vector-space . (In the future, to avoid duplicate effort, we kindly ask that you mention this not only on MO but also here on MSE. Thanks!)

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Thanks, should I delete it here?

Comment: I am not sure if there are clear guidelines for this. Browsing MSE meta, I found some people who chose to delete their MSE post in a similar situation. I have also seen people answer their own question here on MSE to explain the answer(s) from MO in more detail, though I guess the MO answers to this question are already quite understandable. I'm not aware of any community guidelines, so I guess it's up to you.

Comment: [This meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27642/) recommends answering the question yourself, whereas [this meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25345/) recommends removal. Sorry I could not give you a more decisive answer. 